# unable to create new mailboxes on Exchange 2010 after resetting DNS permissions in the domain controller

Tags: permissions, exchange

I have exchange 2010 and a couple of domain controllers. I retested the permissions in AD and DNS (very brilliant thing to do, indeed.. just mocking), we are no longer able to manage exchange server, neither able to add any new mailboxes, error is as follows: Active directory response: 00002098: SecErr: DSID-03150E49, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS)

I no longer see any security groups for excahnge anywhere in the domain controllers. What can I do to restore the correct permissions?

Comment: Give us some details on exactly what you did that caused this problem.

Comment: But the Exchange Schema is still in place... means Exchange is working fine?

Comment: yes, it works fine.. rather the issue is that no one can create a mailbox..

Comment: Joe, wt details do u need?

Comment: What permissions did you change and where did you change them from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**setup /adprep** doesn't work. SP version in Exchange server 2010 installation media is different. In my case, **setup /adprep** will never work because I have already updated my servers to **SP3**.

To make a long story short, I did the following:

**1.** setup **/PrepareLegacyExchangePermissions** from Exchange Server 2010 installation media.

**2.** Under "Active Directory Users and Computers", expand **System** container, right click for properties on **AdminSDHolder**, go to **Security** tab, click **Advanced**, click "**Enable Inheritance**".

and that's it. I am happy to find out that it is possible to clean the rubbish caused by others, finally!!

P.S. Enable Inheritance was required because, under many circumstances after getting Exchange Server 2003/7 upgraded to 2010, permissions had to be applied not just "on this object only", rather on all descendants as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, any details about "resetting the permissions in AD and DNS"?
It's helpful for troubleshooting, or test it in lab to fix it.

Normally, we can re-run Exchange installation with ".\setup /Preparead" only to prepare AD object, not install Exchange server.